# Prepend partial branch name to commit message

Tags: git, githooks

The current branch name convention looks like this:

```
feature/NEU-123
```

I try to create a git hook to prepend a commit message, that the commit looks like this:

```
NEU-123: commit message
```

I have no experience in creating scripts like this. That's why I don't have a starting point and need to try out your approaches.

I've looked up a few Stackoverflow entries but I can't find anything about this specific naming convention.
Also it would be great, if I am on the master branch, or any branch with just a single word branch name, that the complete branch name is prepended.

Already thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not a good idea. A commit is not bound to a specific branch. Why would you like to do so?

Comment: Because I need to identify the commit to a specfic branch. And it is hard to do so, if the branch is merged into the master branch. Each branch is bound to an issue.

Comment: @ElpieKay: in this case, it's not such a bad idea as the branch name was deliberately created to match an issue number in some sort of issue-tracking system. (I prefer to put issue numbers into the commit message *body* rather than the *header* but different groups have different conventions...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [Client-side hook / Committing-Workflow Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks), a prepare-commit-msg could be used in conjunction with a commit template to programmatically insert information.

Example: [`janniks/prepare-commit-msg`](https://github.com/janniks/prepare-commit-msg) which [does get the branch name](https://github.com/janniks/prepare-commit-msg/blob/master/scripts/prepare-commit-msg#L45-L47) (using Ruby, but you can use any scripting language you want):

```rb
# get the current branch name
git_branch_command = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
branch_name, error, result = Open3.capture3(git_branch_command)
```

Same idea in [`ljpengelen/prefix-commit-message`](https://github.com/ljpengelen/prefix-commit-message)

Close to what you are looking for: [`mikhailsidorov/husky-prepare-commit-msg-example`](https://github.com/mikhailsidorov/husky-prepare-commit-msg-example), and its bash [`.githooks/prepare-commit-msg`](https://github.com/mikhailsidorov/husky-prepare-commit-msg-example/blob/adb43d5b99f076fe4d1e4e04eaa374c87d94c804/.githooks/prepare-commit-msg), from [Mikhail Sidorov](https://github.com/mikhailsidorov):

> Example project with `prepare-commit-msg` hook configured to prepend branch name to commit message automatically
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$(echo $1 | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1)
>
> if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
>  BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop test)
> fi
>
> BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
> BRANCH_NAME="${BRANCH_NAME##*/}"
>
> BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
> BRANCH_IN_COMMIT_MSG=$(head -1 $COMMIT_MSG_FILE | grep -c "$BRANCH_NAME")
>
> if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]] && ! [[ $BRANCH_IN_COMMIT_MSG -ge 1 ]]; then 
>  sed -i'.bak' -e "1s/^/$BRANCH_NAME /" $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
> fi
> ```